# SVM Grid search always gives same accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm using libSVM to train a binary classifier on 38 training instances consisting of ~250 features.

Before training I scale the data to [0,1] and perform a grid search to find the best parameters. However, I get the same accuracy results for all combinations of settings. I'm wondering if this indicates a problem, and if so what problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's really hard to say for sure -- could be a bug somewhere. However, 38 training instances isn't a lot, particularly with 250 features. I can easily envision there being one or two local optima in the space of decision functions that classify your 38 instances identically. Even in the best of cases, this little training data with that many features is going to put you at a high risk of overfitting.

Comment: @deong Unfortunately, that is all the data that I have. I'm using the SVM for Authorship Attribution of student essays, I do get 96-98% accuracy so no complaints there. I was mainly curious about whether this indicated a bug :) Thanks for the reply

Comment: @deong I noticed I still get the same "problem" when using for instance 3000 training instances

Comment: How do your parameters vary (in particular, `C`)? Do you have the same number of positive and negative examples? Is the accuracy computed on the train or on the test set?

Comment: What kernel are you using? Are you using c-SVM or nu-SVM (c is the default in libsvm). Try nu-SVM with nu set to .1,.2,.3,etc to .8, do you still get identical results?  How are you test and training sets comprised - are you testing on the training set? Using any cross-validation?

Comment: @Edouard I'm doing a grid-search for the parameters, I think that it uses some sort of cross-validation on the training data to estimate the accuracy. Currently i'm using c-SVM, my training consists of roughly 10% positive and 90% negative data